# AWS Field 'partialFilterExpression' is currently not supported

Tags: mongodb

In AWS Document DB, `MongoDB server version: 4.0.0`, When try to use partialFilterExpression, got error:

```
Field 'partialFilterExpression' is currently not supported
```

The same command in my Mac, `MongoDB server version: 4.0.3`, it works.

Is there any thing to do to turn it on? Or give it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial indexes are not supported in DocumentDB:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-index-properties

| Command | 3.6 | 4.0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TTL | Yes | Yes |
| Unique | Yes | Yes |
| Partial | No | No |
| Case Insensitive | No | No |
| Sparse | Yes | Yes |
| Background | Yes | Yes |